# AutoHotKey - Ending with a blank

Tags: autohotkey

i am trying to build a AutoHotKey that has a **blank at the end**. But i don't get the idea how to achieve it. Documentary doesn't help me neither. Tried " " and `t without results i seek.

The result should be this String:
"2016-02-03 : "

My Script:

```
$F12::
SetTitleMatchMode, 2
FormatTime, xx,, yyyy-MM-dd : " "; This is one type of the date format
SendInput, %xx%
Return
```

This is from the documentary "Ending Characters":

> Unless the asterisk option is in effect, you must type an ending
>   character after a hotstring's abbreviation to trigger it. Ending
>   characters initially consist of the following: -()[]{}':;"/\,.?!`n`t
>   (note that `n is Enter,`t is Tab, and there is a plain space between
>   `n and`t). This set of characters can be changed by editing the
>   following example, which sets the new ending characters for all
>   hotstrings, not just the ones beneath it:
>
> ## Hotstring EndChars -()[]{}:;'"/\,.?!`n`t

Can anyone help my achieve this? Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can explicitly add the space in the SendInput command.

```
$F12::
SetTitleMatchMode, 2
FormatTime, xx,, yyyy-MM-dd : " "; This is one type of the date format
SendInput, %xx%{space}
Return
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can use this syntax:

```
SendInput, % xx " "
```

By using a single percent sign in the beginning, text will be interpreted as variables, unless you put it in quotes. Spaces outside of quotes are ignored.
You can optionally put a dot between the variables and strings if you like:

```
SendInput, % xx . " "
```

There is also the built in variable A_Space which simply contains a space:

```
SendInput, % xx . A_Space
```

or

```
SendInput, %xx%%A_Space%
```